# To find limits of double integral in Polar

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Question is to find the volume of region that lies under the paraboloid $z=x^{2} + y^{2}$ and above triangle in XY PLANE enclosed by the lines $y=x$, $x=0$ and $x+y=2$.

I can clearly see from graph that limits of $\theta $ are from $\pi/4$ to $\pi/2$.But how do i find out $r=f(\theta)$ limits. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract the equation of the top portion from the bottom portion of the solid. In this case,$x^2+y^2-0=x^2+y^2$. Rewrite it in polar coordinates: $x^2+y^2=r^2$.

Hence, volume is $\displaystyle\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^\frac{\pi}{2}\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}}r^2\cdot r \ drd\theta$.

Note: $\frac{2}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}$ is the equation of $x+y=2$ in polar coordinates. I separated $rdrd\theta$ term to emphasize the correcting factor is included.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Look at the vertices of the triangle in question. You have their $(x,y)$ coordinates. What are their $(r,\theta)$ coordinates?